# Passing a function arguments from file + bash

Tags: bash, function

I have a function that accept arguments and build frame outside the text:

```
function Box()
{
  local s=("$@") b w
  for l in "${s[@]}"; do
    ((w<${#l})) && { b="$l"; w="${#l}"; }
  done
  tput setaf 3
  echo " -${b//?/-}-
| ${b//?/ } |"
  for l in "${s[@]}"; do
    printf '| %s%*s%s |\n' "$(tput setaf 4)" "-$w" "$l" "$(tput setaf 3)"
  done
  echo "| ${b//?/ } |
 -${b//?/-}-"
  tput sgr 0
}
```

Box muzi puss would create something nice:

```
--------
| muzi |
| puss |
--------
```

I have a file "bla.txt" which contain this data:

```
192.168.1.1 muzi
192.168.2.2 puzi
192.168.2.2 puzi
```

Id like to somehow pass arguments to the function one line after another from the file, so the result will be like so:

Box "192.168.1.1 muzi" "192.168.2.2 puzi" "192.168.2.2 puzi"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I suggest to rewrite it in awk - will be 1000 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

Read the file into an array and then pass the array properly quoted to the function. Just:

```
mapfile -t arr < bla.txt
Box "${arr[@]}"
```

You could utilize `xargs` or preferably `parallel`:

```
export -f Box
xargs -d '\n' bash -c 'Box "$@"' _ < bla.txt
```